# How to add if condition in the environment section of jenkinsFile

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am writing a jenkins script where I need to initialize the environment based on a parameter (QA/Prod). Following is the script I wrote:

```java
def serverName = ${ServerName} // I get this value from the parametrized job value.
pipeline {
    agent any

    agent any
    tools {
        terraform 'Terraform'
    }
    environment {
        AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = ""
        AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = ""
    }
    stages {
        stage('Set Environment') {
            steps {
                echo "Region is ${AWS_DEFAULT_REGION}"
                echo "Server Name is: "+params.ServerName
                script{
                    if ("QA" == params.ServerName){
                        withEnv(['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID='+credentials ('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID_QA')], ['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY='+credentials ('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY_QA')]){
                            echo "Key is ${AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY}"
                            echo "Key is ${AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY}"
                        }
                    }
                    if ("PROD" == params.ServerName){
                        withEnv(["AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=credentials('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID_PROD')"], ["AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=credentials('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY_PROD')"]){
                            echo "Key is ${AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY}"
                            echo "Key is ${AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY}"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

I am getting the following error:

> 00:59:22  java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Expected named arguments
> but got
> [[AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=@credentials(=AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID_QA)],
> [AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=@credentials(=AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY_QA)]]
> 00:59:22      at
> org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.DSL.parseArgs(DSL.java:588)
> 00:59:22      at
> org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.DSL.parseArgs(DSL.java:521)
> 00:59:22      at
> org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.DSL.invokeStep(DSL.java:220)
> 00:59:22      at
> org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.DSL.invokeMethod(DSL.java:179)
> 00:59:22      at
> org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsScript.invokeMethod(CpsScript.java:122)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
pipeline {
    environment {
            AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = GET_AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID(env.serverName)
            AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = GET_AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY(env.serverName)
    }
    
    //your rest of the pipeline code
}
def GET_AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID(Server_Name) {
    if("QA".equals(Server_Name)) {
        return credentials ('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID_QA');
    } else if ("PROD".equals(Server_Name)) {
        return credentials ('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID_PROD');
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}
def GET_AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY(Server_Name) {
    if("QA".equals(Server_Name)) {
        return credentials ('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY_QA');
    } else if ("PROD".equals(Server_Name)) {
        return credentials ('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY_PROD');
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Getting this:  `org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
00:49:09  WorkflowScript: 9: Not a valid section definition: "if ("QA" == params.ServerName){
00:49:09              echo "Server is ${serverName}"
00:49:09              environment {
00:49:09                  AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = credentials ('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID_QA')
00:49:09                  AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = credentials('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY_QA')
00:49:09              }
00:49:09          }". Some extra configuration is required. @ line 9, column 9.
`

Comment: will the serverName variable will have a value QA or PROD ? and is serverName set as env variable ?

Comment: Yes, the server name will have value QA or PROD. This is a parameterized job and the value will come dynamically. I also tried with `params.ServerName` and echoed the value. The value comes fine.

Comment: I have also updated the post with updated script and error.

Comment: Updated the answer. Assuming that you are running parameterized build

Comment: Thanks. Getting this error now:

`01:12:12  Error: error configuring Terraform AWS Provider: error validating provider credentials: error calling sts:GetCallerIdentity: InvalidClientTokenId: The security token included in the request is invalid.`

Any clue?

Comment: check your token in Jenkins if it is correct or not and ensure the type of credential you are using is secret Text

Comment: Looks like this is not working: `credentials ('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID_QA')`. When I echo this value, I get the following:

`10:11:47  AWS ACCESS KEY OF QA IS ===== $AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID_QA`